# timevar not specified - IPW model

Tags: r

I'm working on building a marginal structural model using inverse probability of treatment weights to estimate the longitudinal relationship between categorical variables. If I understood correctly, I do not need to specify my "timevar" when my family is binomial, unless it is a survival analysis. However, when I ran my script, I received an error:

```
Error in ipwtm(exposure = co_desp_l6m, family = "binomial", link = "logit",  : 
  No timevar specified
```

Below is my code:

```
stableM <- ipwtm(
  exposure = co_desp_l6m,
  family = "binomial",
  link = "logit",
  numerator = ~ 1,
  denominator = ~ binge_inj_l6m + cd4_l6m + employment_l6m + hcv + heavy_alc + heroin_inj_l6m + heroin_noninj_l6m + illigal_inc_l6m + jail_l6m + unstable_housing + age + female + white,
  id = code,
  type = all,
  na.action = na.omit,
  data = df
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a very similar problem as you. I checked their source code on Github (just do a Ctrl+F search with the object "timevar"). It actually occurs in line 50, and then the next occurrence is just line 150. But everything regarding the binomial model is between line 63 and line 144. That saying, when your model is binomial, actually the model building doesn't involve timevar at all. But in line 28, they have a generic check of the existence of the timevar, regardless of the model category, and pops up an error message when it's missing. So I would say this is just a small bug of the program. Just make up a timevar and specify it in your model to let it work. There will be no harm. I hope my explanation helps. Cheers!

Yuhang